# Laravel Fortify redirect with message after registration

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-fortify

I am using Laravel fortify to register new users in my web app. I receive payment during registration and it creates a user but I want to show and alert message on home page after login.
If I try using

```
return redirect()->route('home')->with('success','You are logged in!');
```

it does not work says this method should return a `$user`.
How can I achieve  this?

Comment: Do you have some named route, something like `Route::get('/home/{id}/profile', function ($id) { // })->name('profile');`?

Comment: Yes I have named all the routes

Comment: If you save the logged in user id in some variable, `$user` for example, try to pass it as second parameter to the `route` method, something like `return redirect()->route('home', ['id' => $user )->with('success','You are logged in!'); `

Comment: Thanks..I just stored message in a flash session and then showed it on page